# How do you update Powershell Core to latest version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, powershell-core

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 VM with Powershell Core 6.1.2 installed and I want to update it to the latest PowerShell Core version.

How do I do that?

Do I follow the install instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6#ubuntu-1804 and install the latest version on top of the old version?

Do I remove the old version first and then install the new version? How do you do that?

Is there a tool in Powershell Core to perform the update?

Comment: It depends on how ***you*** did install. For future installations I'd [Install](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/07/install-powershell-snap-ubuntu-18-04/) and [update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760823/how-can-i-update-all-snap-packages) via snap (works also with 19.04).

Comment: Thanks. I had assumed I had installed it some more complicated way, but it turned out it was listed in apt-get so I was able to upgrade it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44122/how-to-upgrade-a-single-package-using-apt-get) following should work:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade powershell
```

Comment: Thanks to moerwald and @LotPings.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y powershell
```

Comment: Why not just upgrade PowerShell if it's already installed?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` will update the repos to the latest and then 
`sudo apt-get install -y powershell` will install latest version of powershell without any issues.